# Error: Struct already definded in *.Obj

Tags: visual-c++

Help, I'm using VC++ and I always get the LNK2005 and LNK1169 Error when running my script, can you guys please tell me why it's happening and how to fix it, Thank you!
Code:

In the Main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Modifier.h"
using namespace std;
HWND myconsole = GetConsoleWindow();
HDC mydc = GetDC(myconsole);
int main()
{
if (Input.beg("Hello"))
{
    cout << "World";
}
    cin.ignore();
}
```

In "Modifier.cpp"

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
struct {
    bool beg(string a)
    {
        string b;
        getline(cin, b);
        if (b == a)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
} Input;
```

In "Modifier.h"

```
#include "Modifier.cpp"
```

Comment: Errg, will someone help, Please?

Comment: You must change your header declaration: you're inadvertently declaring a different, global "Input" variable in every .cpp that includes "Modifier.h".

Comment: why you include Modifier.cpp in Modifier.h?

Comment: FoggyDay, Would you know how to fix this, I'm used to C# but I'm starting to use C++ for more expandable programs.

Comment: JosEdu, I thought it would be useful so I could `#define` things to    be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change your header declaration: you're inadvertently declaring a different, global "Input" variable in every .cpp that includes "Modifier.h".

SUGGESTION:

```
// Modifier.h
#ifndef MODIFER_H
#define MODIFIER_H

struct  Input {
    bool beg(string a)
    {
        string b;
        getline(cin, b);
        if (b == a)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
};
#endif
```

Then, in Modifier.cpp:

```
#include "Modifier.h"

struct Input globalInput;
```

You should *not* include a .cpp in a .h.  You should include headers in source files, not vice versa.

And you should definitely consider using a "class" instead of a "struct".  Because, frankly, that's what your "Input" is: just a method, no state/no data.

Comment: I didn't know you could pre-define a struct, Thank you. and testing if it's already been defined, I didn't even know how to do that (facepalm), thank you.